# How can I crop a picture in a circular shape just like Instagram profile picture

Tags: java, android, kotlin, github

I want the user to pick an image from gallery and crop it [like this], similar to Instagram profile picture

[image]

Is there a package or something to help?

All the packages I found don't have cropping in a circular shape , I'm expecting maybe that there is a package that I didn't find or another way to do that

Comment: You can use the Android ShapeableImageView

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this, and change the shape to `app:cropme_overlay_shape="circle"`

https://github.com/TakuSemba/CropMe